# Compare Two Arrays in Javascript to Find Specific Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

I have two arrays. One of the arrays contains all the values needed, and the other array contains specific values needed. Using javascript, I have to figure out a way to print the specific values (the ones that appear in both arrays) to the console with a label "menuitem" and the other values printed to the console without the label. For example:

If these are my arrays 
array1 = [apple, banana, pear, strawberry] 
array2 = [apple, banana]

The console would have to display:
menuitem: apple 
menuitem: banana
pear 
strawberry

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const array1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'strawberry'];
const array2 = ['apple', 'banana'];

for(const a1 of array1) {
  if(array2.includes(a1)) {
    console.log('menuitem:', a1);
  } else {
    console.log(a1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Was happy to help ;)